# Clojure atoms convert vectors to lists?

Tags: clojure

I wanted a Clojure vector in an atom to model a stateful FIFO (push to the end, pop from the beginning).  tried

```
(def stack (atom []))
```

then `push` as follows:

```
(swap! stack #(conj % 1))
(swap! stack #(conj % 2))
```

expecting

```
[1 2]
```

but getting

```
(2 1)
```

Not a big deal, it just means that I must reverse (O(n)) the value of the atom (persistent list) to get the items in the order than I pushed them (e.g., a stream of imperative commands to a virtual machine in order). Still, it was a surprise.

Is there a clojure.core FIFO I can pack into an atom? I thought of `priority-map`, but it seems overkill. The examples for `swap!` on clojuredocs.org use lists or maps, not quite what I wanted. I found lots of samples by googling "FIFO Clojure," but some are a bit rich, e.g., clojure.core.cache (map-like and not vector-like); amalloy's ring-buffer (external dependency). Looking for something really small and straightforward. I didn't see an answer in the automatic suggestions from StackOverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something is not quite right in the wider context of your code; I'm assuming that you have much more going on than what's in the example you posted?

Here's the result in my REPL and what I'd expect:

```
user=> (def stack (atom []))
#'user/stack
user=> (swap! stack #(conj % 1))
[1]
user=> (swap! stack #(conj % 2))
[1 2]
user=> @stack
[1 2]
```

When using Vectors, items are added to the end of the collection. The result that you're seeing looks like the behaviour you'd get if `stack` was a list instead, e.g. adding to the front:

```
user=> (def stack (atom '()))
#'user/stack
user=> (swap! stack #(conj % 1))
(1)
user=> (swap! stack #(conj % 2))
(2 1)
user=> @stack
(2 1)
```

So I'm wondering if somewhere in your code, you've somehow ended up defining a list, rather than a vector.

Comment: The context was a bunch of repeated tests of pushing and popping. Looks like when I pop the last item off a vector stack, the atom is left with an empty list and not an empty vector. Subsequent pushes conj onto the list and not a vector. The fix is easy in my pop function --- put back in an empty vector if the last pop empties the stack.

Comment: No, `(pop [1])` is `[]`. That's not your problem. Now, if you ever call `rest` on it, or `seq`, that could make it a list.

Comment: I wrote my own (stupid, wrong) pop function that called `(partial drop 1)` and inadvertently doing the conversion. Fixing to use the built-in pop.

Comment: Well, the built-in `pop` pops from the end of the vector, so I think it implements LIFO in the most straightforward usage. I'm provisionally going with a `(swap! fifo (fn [_] []))` when the seq in the atom is empty.

Comment: If you want a queue instead of a stack, just use the built-in queue at `clojure.lang.PersistentQueue`.